# Edit object properties by using a two ways binding directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a json that I want in a ng-repeat show an input per item for editing.

The json:

```
$scope.setup.configuration = {
    "filename": "configuration", 
    "fileversion": "01.00.0000"
};
```

The directive (uses "=" in scope for two ways binding):

```
 app.directive("kSetupOption", ['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            scope:{
                key:"=",
                option:"="
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            template:'<p>{{key}}: <input ng-model="option" /></p>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              }
            }
    }]);
```

The problem is that the 2 way binding works correctly with this:

```
<input ng-model="setup.configuration.filename">
```

But not with this code using the directive:

```
<k-setup-option
    ng-repeat="(key , option) in setup.configuration" 
    option="option" 
    key="key" ></k-setup-option>
```

Please see the demo in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JFpWIadrsLvOkJgzTFvv?p=preview) . thanks.

Comment: plunker. link is not working please edit it

Comment: @Fabrice As `ng-repeat` is a directive every time it iterates, it generates new instance has it own scope, tough you mention `=` its doesn't matter . updated your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/HdclYxw1mCAgpQYR38Ia?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Move the `ng-repeat` inside the directive:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive("kSetupOption", function () {
    return {
            scope:{
                config:"<",
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            template:`<p ng-repeat="(key,option) in config">
                       {{key}}: <input ng-model="config[key]" />
                      </p>`,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            }
    };
})
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var MC = $scope;
  MC.setup = {};
  MC.setup.configuration = {
            "filename": "configuration", 
            "fileversion": "01.00.0000"
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    
    <k-setup-option config="setup.configuration"></k-setup-option>
  
    <h2>setup.configuration:</h2> 
    <div style="background-color:#f9f0b3">{{setup.configuration}}</div>  
</body>
```

When using `ng-repeat`, binding `ng-model` to primitives (`ng-model="option"`) creates the data hiding problem described in "[What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)"

Avoid that by binding `ng-model` to a property of an object, i.e, `config[key]`.